# Internet Explorer 9 Rending Engine and Quirks Mode

Tags: internet-explorer

**What general rendering engine will IE9 use?**
I've heard that it's moving to WebKit, but the latest news from MS [via their blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2009/11/18/an-early-look-at-ie9-for-developers.aspx) hints that it's a proprietary engine similar to the previous iterations but with more oomph via DirectX rendering.

**Why Ask this Now?**
My question is due to the fact that a lot of legacy web applications still utilize quirks mode in browsers, and I'm curious if IE9 is going to force those out of existence, or force supporters of that legacy software to push their users to continue using IE7-IE8.

**EDIT!**

**What's the question?**
This question was closed as subjective and argumentative. I didn't mean to start a debate, here's my question: **IS IE9 GOING TO BE WEBKIT OR NOT?**

"No one knows" is an acceptable answer, but I thought there might be a news article or an announcement by MS stating whether it would be or not. So far I've found nothing.

Comment: **Avoid asking questions that are subjective, argumentative, or require extended discussion. This is not a discussion board, this is a place for questions that can be answered!**

Comment: I'm sorry, I wasn't meaning to start a debate. My question was if IE9 had declared if it was using WebKit as a rendering engine or not, because I can't find any news that states if it has.
The answer to this question would be yes or no, with the option to expound upon whether this would affect legacy applications that require quirks mode to function properly.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that they will move away from their Trident-Engine. Simply because they're working on the Acid3-Test at the moment, at least they are making now 32 Points, if they would switch to WebKit they would make immediately 100 Points.

Also, if they would move to WebKit they would acknowledge that they have failed by building there own and that they need to use OpenSource to stay competitive.

This is just my opinion...might be wrong.